# WooCommerce - How to remove Basket on Top Nav?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help on removing this woocommerce basket on front page in top navigation

https://house-energy.dk/

Answer (score 0):

The right way is doing it via theme options. But if there is no such option, then you can use this simple CSS to hide that element:

```
<style>#menu-topmenu .shopping-cart{display:none}</style>
```